# add new row after certain column in tables

Tags: jquery

Really need as I struggled here but to no avail..start pulling my hair..Okay here's the scenario I have raw data from DB which is I wanna display in table.

but my problem is how to display the result in 4 columns and the new row is created after the columns=4 until end of record...I know how to done using PHP by using modulus but in Jquery..\0/ I have being struggle all days for now...

here's are my attempt

```
 $.ajax({type :'GET',url : 'getalbums.php',dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data){
                $.each(data, function(i,item){

                    var lendata = data.length;
                    var columns = 2;

                    for(var i=0;i<lendata;i++){
                        if(i % columns == 0) {
                            $("<tr>").appendTo("#tablealbumphotos");    
                        }
                        $("<td>YESSSS</td>").appendTo("#tablealbumphotos");
                        if((i % columns) == (columns - 1) || (i + 1) == lendata) {
                            $("</tr><tr><td>YESSSS</td></tr>").appendTo("#tablealbumphotos");
                        }
                    }

                        });

                    }
                    ,error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    }
                });
```

and here are my HTML

```
<table id="tablealbumphotos" class="tblphotos">
<!-- display the resutl here in grid format -->        

</table>
```

Hope someone will shed me some light on how to goes for it..really need help..TQ

==================================**EDITT**===========================================

Thanks for the reply @olivieradam666

could you pls be more eloborate by this statements "Your server should send you an array of nbRows objects containing 4 fields (1 per column)." another things is your provide code will assign the result in grid regardless the total lenght of data eg:

col1 col2  col3      col4
col5 col6  col7      col8
col9 col10 undefined undefined

suppose to for total records of 10 and columns=4

col1 col2  col3      col4
col5 col6  col7      col8
col9 col10

Any hints tq

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
success : function(data){
  var lendata = data.length;
  var columns = 2;

  for (var row = 0; row < lendata / columns; row++) {
    var tr = $('<tr>').appendTo("#tablealbumphotos");
    for (var i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
      tr.append($("<td>YESSSS</td>"));//here you should use data[row*columns + i]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your server should send you an array of nbRows objects containing 4 fields (1 per column). This would allow for a much cleaner javascript (no modulo and colums indexed by name)

Comment: if you sent [[00, 01, 02, 03], [10, 11, 12, 13], [20, 21, 22, 23]] then knowing the number of rows would be easy. Even better: [{name: 'Diego', age: 22}, {name:'Jojo', age: 23}] and then put name in column 0, age in column 1...